# Getting Yellow Background color on link

Tags: color, pdfcomment

can anybody tell me how to apply a yellow background color on pdf links (especially on hovering the mouse over the link). For example, I would like to have the same yellow background effect that appears for example on the Contents section of this pdf (pdfcomment docs). http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/pdfcomment.pdf

Comment: The tex-file is also available at CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/pdfcomment.tex

Comment: I found the tex file, Marco. And thx for the link, by the way. But Im a newbie and while I was looking at the tex code, I didnt find anything that could give me a tip about how to set a yellow background on the content-links while hovering my mouse on them.  If anybody has another suggestions, let me know plz.

Comment: I think you're right, Andrew. I've tested the same pdf on Adobe Reader and the yellow background's gone. Thx for the explanation, again.

Comment: As a short addition, the hover effect is enabled (in viewer that supports it) when you load the `hyperref` package in your .tex file. In the file linked by Marco Daniel the `hyperref` package is automatically loaded by the `attachfile` package. If you remove it the yellow background goes away.

Answer (score 4):

[Converting Andrew Kepert's comment to a answer]

Interaction with mouseovers (e.g. a hover colour) is done by the pdf viewer, and will vary from viewer to viewer. For example the pdfcomment.pdf pdf linked above will use yellow mouseover highlights within firefox's built-in pdf viewer but not in Adobe Reader or MacOS X Preview. Interaction within Adobe Reader can be done with forms, javascript, etc but this won't work in other viewers.