# Hypersetup settings to get glowing text in firefox PDF viewer

Tags: hyperref

The `hyperref` package has a readme with settings to make all links glow (with a yellow background) when hovering over them (with the mouse) in Mozilla Firefox. See the link [here](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/rhigginbottom/latex/resources/hyperref-manual.pdf). I can't find the source file for this manual anywhere.

I want to use the same effects in my own PDF, which I also intend to make available for Mozilla Firefox viewers.

Currently I got the following code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=yellow,
    linkcolor=red,
    citecolor=red,
    hypertexnames=false,
    pdfhighlight=/O,
    anchorcolor=yellow,
    }%
```

I am fiddling around with these `hypersetup` settings, but I'm getting right about nothing done.

Does anyone know the settings used in the `hyperref` manual?

Comment: You could ask Heiko Oberdiek about the setup. He is an active user of TeX.SX.

Comment: I think @Heiko Oberdiek also made the `hyperref` package and its manual, so he should have an answer here.

Comment: Or you could look at the source of the manual...

Comment: I stated specifically that I couldn't find the source of the manual.

Comment: @Euryis: I mentioned Heiko Oberdiek just because he is the author of `hyperref` ;-)

Comment: The CTAN hyperref README says: **The subversion source repository for hyperref is hosted at Puszcza:
  https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/svn/?group=hyperref
It offers anonymous access** Perhaps the source of the manual is there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Yellow Background color on link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111934/getting-yellow-background-color-on-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to conclusion that this graphic setting is apparently (sort of) default.

Using these commands, I've pretty much nailed the intended effect:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,% Don't draw a box around links, instead color every piece of text, which is a link
linkcolor=red,% Color them red
hypertexnames=false,% Use a default object counter to count links (chapters, sections, etc. appear as 1,2,3 instead of 1, 1.1, etc.)
pdfhighlight=/N% When clicking a link and holding the mouse button, don't use any graphical effects - i.e. the alternative would be to behave like a "button" which is pressed within the PDF
}%
```

Comment: funny it only works with firefox right? if we open in acrobat professional there is no glowing...

Comment: @SergioParreiras Seems like it. I am unaware of integration of the same effect in any software.