# make href in Latex change color when hover above text

Tags: color, hyperlink, href

Does anyone know how to make a link change color when hover above it in Latex? For example, I have `welcome to \href{https://www.google.com}{Google}` I want it to appear like normal text (does not have any effect) `welcome to Google` But when I hover the word `Google` , it will turn blue.

Comment: such effects are rather hard to achieve in a consistent way in different pdf readers (PDF features unrelated to latex)

Comment: I know that, but I still want to make it turn blue when hovering. I still don't know how

Comment: do you have _any_ pdf that has a working hover effect when used with the pdf reader you use. If you do latex could most likely generate the same but otherwise this will be hard to answer.

Comment: Some viewers change color on hover by default in any document that has links, for example the built-in pdf viewer in Firefox. So if you want this effect for yourself then you can use that viewer. If you want the effect for other people reading your document then it is not possible (unless you can convince everybody that reads your document to use Firefox to view the file). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111934/getting-yellow-background-color-on-link.